# My old manager has now become my skip-level manager, how to survive?

Tags: politics

I had a dreadful manager.
I had to fight a lot, but I managed to move to a new manager. I am very happy with this person, one of the best managers I ever had.
We lost a very senior manager, and my previous manager, who was in a more limited role but has been in the company the most, is covering "ad interim"... for 12-18 months.
Now my old manager has effectively become my skip-manager, and he has been putting pressure on my new manager to take me out of meetings, exclude me from projects, and limit my visibility in general.
In his new role, he was able to NOT promote at all a key strategic initiative which I have been working very productively on with my new manager, effectively hiding our initiative from senior execs.

There is now increasing tension between me and my new manager. In parallel, my old manager managed to take a team member away from my current team citing "emergency due to covid".

This is a nightmare, and I don't know how to fix it. Soon my manager will try to get rid of me, because of the pressure.

I want to protect my new manager, but I don't know what can be done.

Comment: This seems like politics, where without any information at all about the background etc., it's close to impossible to give useful advice. How about the standard: Look for a new job?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Start looking for a new job.
2. Find a new job.
3. Optional -Talk with HR and Senior execs. Tell them everything you wrote here.
4. If they don't listen and change their ways, leave.

Comment: Right to the point on this.

Comment: #3 and #4 are optional. I'd recommend thinking about whether them solving the issue in your favour is a likely outcome (and absent strong evidence to the contrary, assume the answer is no). If it won't go your way, then just quit. #3 and #4 will unnecessarily burn bridges without any benefit to you.

Comment: At the same time as 1 - if the company is big enough look for a new role that doesn't report to either of these people.